# Trying to run XobotOs in Ubuntu 12 - fails

Tags: c#, android, mono, xobotos

I was planning to build XobotOs on my machine. Before building, I wanted to execute the prebuilt version which is `binaries/managed/XobotOs.exe`. For this, as seen in the included screen casts (`binaries/managed/videos`), I ran the following command from `binaries/managed/`:

`mono XobotOs.exe Fragments.dll`

But it crashes with the following log in terminal:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'XobotOS.Runtime.XobotActivityManager' from assembly 'XobotOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a30277e6179bbc2'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'XobotOS.Runtime.XobotActivityManager' from assembly 'XobotOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a30277e6179bbc2'.
```

What I understand is that this is a `mono` crash. Can anybody shed any light on what is happening and how to solve this?

This is the output of `mono --version`:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Comment: Suggest you ask this on some suitable XobotOS forum rather than a general purpose programming forum.

Comment: It felt like a problem with mono itself, and not about the os binary, hence asked